# Is there any kind of backup for the data that is deleted during NAND flash block erase?

Tags: flash, data-storage, nand-flash

In NAND Flash, the whole block is erased.How is the data in that block that is not intended to be erased, gets recovered after it is erased? Is there some kind of Flash Memory Management Unit that helps in recovering or relocating that data?

Comment: How is that "not secure"?

Comment: Since you are losing programmed data, after erasing the whole block.

Comment: Block erase memory 101: if you want to keep part of the data in a block when modifying it, you have to copy that data elsewhere, erase the block, then write the parts to be retained back.  Often in practice this is combined with wear leveling, so the modified version gets written elsewhere and the original block is erased and freed for much later re-use with entirely different data.

Comment: There are endless write-ups that explain NAND block management such as this: http://eng.umd.edu/~blj/CS-590.26/micron-tn2919.pdf  ...or this... https://www.kingston.com/us/community/ArticleDetail?ArticleId=1&Article-Title=SSD-Flash-Memory-and-Write-Amplification

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji Still not sure how that qualifies as "not secure". You can erase or overwrite data on any rewritable storage medium -- does that make anything other than write-once media "insecure"?

Comment: @duskwuff what i meant was that if there is any protected data that is write-protected, that will also get erased (what I thought till now) and my meaning of "insecure" hence.

Comment: _Secure_ can mean many things. It's not only for hiding data.

Comment: First we need to know what you mean by "secure". To some people, the ability to keep crucial data safe, whatever happens, is "secure". To others, the ability to erase data to prevent others seeing it is "secure". As these two meanings are pretty much mutually exclusive, the question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: If writing "secure" is the reason for downvoting, you can now see my question modified. I hope that helps. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the memory device's software driver who is responsible for managing physical memory where entire blocks of data are erased.

Several types of physical memory over write or erase entire blocks of data. Hard Disk Drives and Flash Memory to name two. Normally, a block of memory is only used for a single file.  If a file is larger then one block of memory, several blocks can be used. So if a file is deleted, the block or all the blocks associated with that file are deleted.

It is unusual to share data from several files in a single block of memory.  But if this occurs, it would be the responsibility of the storage device's software driver to copy the parts of the block to be preserved to another block before erasing the older block of memory.

If this is an embedded application there may be no storage device software driver.  That is, the embedded application manages a block memory device directly.  In such a case, the embedded programmer needs to be very careful in how they manage the memory device so as not to erase wanted data.

Comment: Hard disk drives do not use block erase, you can re-write any sector without first performing an erase. Solid State Drives based on NAND flash do however use block management and have to do block erases at times. Block erases are avoided  because they slow the storage throughput rate down. In most Flash management schemes the new data is written to initialized blocks and the old block added to a free list which can be erased in the background.

Comment: Ok, I reworded the answer to include "over write" as well.